# disable delete media wordpress

Tags: wordpress, media

Here's what I've been trying to figure out how to do for hours now.

I want the author role to be able to upload content into the media library from their posts, and to be able to view the entire media library.  What I don't want is to let the author role delete any media, even their own.

I've thought about automatically switching authors to a 'media' user upon upload completion, but I was hoping there'd be a cleaner way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in capability for "delete_media."  I think this is encompassed by "delete_posts," since uploads are treated as posts.  (Note that authors can delete only their own posts and attachments.)

Adding a role or capability is possible, but you'd have to replace the default media admin screens, where the delete action is controlled by the "delete_posts" cap.  You don't want to mess with the core files `upload.php` etc.  So you'd have to restrict access to them, then write your own panels for authors.  You probably don't want to do this. :-)

There's a better way, however.  If you assign uploads to an administrator when they are saved then authors will not be able to delete them.  You can use the `add_attachment` and `edit_attachment` action hooks to change the `post_author` to an administrator id.

Hope that helps.

Comment: problem though when I do that: when the user uploads the attachment and the author is immediately changed, they can't seem to edit the attachment to insert it into their post.  Maybe if there was a way to make a certain user 'shareable' that is read and editable but not deletable?  I already have delete posts disabled for the author role, but that doesn't seem to affect media or the ability to move posts to the trash.  Hmmm...

Comment: This is an interesting problem. What you're trying to do is a totally valid use case, but I don't believe there's any way to do it without completely rewriting core WP admin panels, since trashing and deleting attachments is controlled by `current_user_can('delete_posts')`.  WordPress needs to add a filter to `current_user_can`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of places where WordPress will let users delete images, so trying to hide them all can be challenging (and dangerous, because a new plug-in or version of WordPress could add another). However, you can add the following function to prevent deletions and throw an error (not pretty, but effective). You could enhance this by adding a custom capability for deleting images, if you wanted a finer level of control.

```
add_action('delete_attachment', 'DontDeleteMedia', 11, 1);
function DontDeleteMedia($postID)
{
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        exit('You cannot delete media.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your functions.php file:

```
add_action('media_row_actions','users_own_attachments', 2, 1);
function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {
    if( !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) ){
        unset($wp_query_obj['delete']);
        return $wp_query_obj;
    }
}
```